# Youtube API - Search multiple author / uploader?

Tags: api, video, youtube, youtube-api, author

I want to search multiple author/uploader videos with a link. Youtube API documentation says:  **the author parameter contains a comma-separated list of up to 20 YouTube usernames.**

I try this but no result found:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&author=cokkomikizbiz,srknrzy
```

*author 1: cokkomikizbiz*

*author 2: srknrzy*

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, it takes the comma as AND...

I am using q to search the uploader instead, any better way to do this?